# Regular Expression question

Tags: regex

For an academic assignment, I need to make a regular expression to match a word with the following specifications:

- Word length >= 1 and <= 8
- Contains letters, digits, and underscore
- First digit can only be a letter
- Word is not A,X,S,T or PC,SW

I tried this regex but can't continue (My big problem is to make the word not equal to PC and SW)

```
([a-zA-Z&&[^AXST]])|([a-zA-Z][\w]{0,7})
```

But in the previous regex I didn't handle the that it is not PC and SW

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?:^|\s)(?!PC)(?!SW)(?!A|S|T|X)(\w{1,8})`

[Explain this?](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3A%5E%7C%5Cs%29%28%3F%21PC%29%28%3F%21SW%29%28%3F%21A%7CS%7CT%7CX%29%28%5Cw%7B1%2C8%7D%29)

Highly suggest using an interactive regex tool for things like this. I use either http://regex.powertoy.org/ or http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ Then just play with them till you get it...

Comment: That "Explain" thing is pretty nice!

Comment: If prefix is allowed (e.g. `PCI` is okay), then the lookahead needs `$`, i.e. `(?!PC$)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative-lookahead `(?!pattern)`

```
^(?!(?:A|X|S|T|PC|SW)$)(?=[A-Za-z])(\w{1,8}$)
```

#### regular-expressions.info

- [Positive and Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

[rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a pretty good interactive regex tool as well.